# YouTube iFrame Breaking jQuery

Tags: jquery, iframe, youtube

I want to do something seemingly simple - embed a YouTube player on my page. However, it's breaking my FlexSliders on my page. There is supposed to be a carousel at the top of the page and one at the bottom left.

Take a look: http://www.maplemountainchorus.org/mandy/index2.html

Am I just missing something?

This is what I'm using for my YouTube:

```
<div id="youTube">
    <iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="400" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=playlist&list=PLqJ3d9oC51bYbad5C_43lNPSJdUibM2J3&showinfo=1" frameborder="0"  allowfullscreen />
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JS console error is

```
Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.youtube.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.maplemountainchorus.org".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.
```

Try getting rid of the `https://` in your YouTube iframe tag

You could also take a look at your closing iframe tags.  Iframe tags are not singleton tags and must end with a `</iframe>` and not a `/>`.

Comment: That was it - I removed the "s" from http:// on the YouTube video reference in the iframe and that fixed it! Thank you!!